# When I update the Lightning Templates through the Eclipse IDE, they become un-editable through the Lightning Interface?

Tags: lightning, email-template, eclipse

I have a scenario where I have a Custom Email Template A, with some custom styling, configured from the Admin Setup(Setup->Email Templates->New Custom Email Template). I also have another Lightning Email Template B, that I have created and saved from the Lightning Interface("Save as new template").

Now I want to update the style of both of them **through the Eclipse IDE**, and I can do that correctly, but now when the Lightning Template B is selected for usage, from Lightning, the email is not editable anymore.

Furthermore, this template shows up at the Custom Email templates, from the Unfiled Public Email Templates list, under setup.

Question, is there a way to apply custom styling to the Lightning Templates and then be able to deploy them through the Eclipse IDE?